# Section and paragraph name in the header using the package scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

How may I get the currrent Section name at the left position  and the current Paragraph name  at the center position in the header of a scrbook (one page mode) ?

Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to demonstrate what you have so far so that other users can build on it.

Comment: What should be in the header if there are more than one section or paragraph on a page? And what should be in the header if the page has only sections? Or only a chapter? Or ...?

Comment: In fact I don't have even the beginning of a working example, sorry.

Comment: I would be please to have the names of the last section and the last paragraph present on a page. By construction my document has always at least a section in it, a section has always paragraphs and a paragraph is always in a section. There should be no strange situation where there is neither section nor paragraph in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you will get trouble with this decision for the header ...

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[autooneside=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[paragraph]{section}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}
\chead{\rightbotmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{Section One}
\paragraph{A Paragraph in Section One}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section Two}
\paragraph{A Paragraph in Section Two}
\lipsum[2]
\paragraph{Another Paragraph in Section Two}
\lipsum[3-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution is not perfect in term of paragraphs follow up. Each section beeing composed of many small paragraphs, a better approach would be to have in the header both the names of the last and first paragraphs  beginning before and after the current page. These names beeing empty when corresponding to paragraphs not existing as at beginning and end of a section. This would be like a header for a dictionnary. But I have no idea how this could be implemented except by a very time consuming hand writing at the beginning of each paragraph. Anyway this solution is better than nothing for me.